# Google Play INSTALL_REFERRER sends at inconsistent times based on method of app open

Tags: android, google-play

I am doing some testing around INSTALL_REFERRER and noticed that how I open the app after installing from Google Play determines at what time the INSTALL_REFERRER is received by the app.

I'm using Steve Miller's awesome Referrer Test app to see the timestamps of the events:
http://stevemiller.net/ReferrerTest/

Here are my test steps:

1. Basically I just visit the url on device with some referrer value set:
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.stevemiller.android.referrertest&referrer=blah
2. This opens the app in Play Store, I press the install button.
3. Once the install is complete, I now have two options - press "OPEN" inside the Play app, or press the notification "Referrer Test - Successfully installed".

Results:

If I pressed OPEN from the Play app, the referrer takes in the order of seconds to be received by the app.

If I pressed the notification, the referrer takes in the order of milliseconds to be received.

What is the cause of this difference? I do notice that when I open from notification, there is some delay in starting the app, possibly waiting for referrer to send? While pressing OPEN starts the Activity immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is going to have the answer to this unless they have intimate knowledge on how the Google Play app is designed. Are you trying to accomplish anything specific?

Comment: I also asked about this on the Google forums, this is just for general knowledge for anyone else using referrer.